# Designing "relevance-based" search?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, search, relevance

In my application (PHP/MySQL/JS), I have a search functionality built in. One of the search criteria contains checkboxes for various options, and as such, some results would be more relevant than others, should they contain more or less of each option.

> i.e. Options are A and B, and if I search for both options A and B, Result 1 containing only option A is 50% relevent, while Result 2 containing both options A and B is 100% relevant.

Prior, I'd just be doing simple SQL queries based on form input, but this one's a little harder, since it's not as simple as data LIKE "%query%", but rather, some results are more valuable to some search queries, and some aren't.

I have absolutely no idea where to begin... does anybody have relevant (ha!) reading material to direct me to?

**Edit**: After mulling it over, I'm thinking something involving an SQL script to get the raw data, followed by many many rounds of parsing is something I'd have to do...

Nothing cacheable, though? :(

Comment: How are options A and B stored in your tables ?

Comment: In a table with 1 or 0 based on the option. But this would eventually be mixed into other search criteria...

Comment: Added an answer, make sure to check it out and comment with questions.

Comment: forgot to mention my method is cacheable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at the lucence project
it is available in many languages

this is the php port
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html

it indexes the items to search and returns the relevant weighted search results, eg better then select x from y where name like '%pattern%' style searching

Comment: @julian, i just thought you may be able to gleen something from the weighting process they use, as that is essentially what you want to do. weight your results so the most relevant comes to the top

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a powerful search engine, like solr. While you could implement this on top of mysql, it's already provided out of the box with other tools.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: do the comparisons and sum the results.  The higher the sum, the more criteria match.

How about a (stupid) table like this:

- name
- dob_year
- dob_month
- dob_day

Find the person who shares the most of the three date components with 3/15/1980:

```
SELECT (dob_year = 1980) + (dob_month = 3) + (dob_day = 15) as strength, name
from user
order by strength desc
limit 1
```

A good WHERE clause and index would be required to keep you from doing a table scan, but...

You could even add a weight to a column, e.g.

```
SELECT ((dob_year = 1980)*2)
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Given your answer to my comment, here's an example on how you might do it:

First the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(80) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `criteria` (
 `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `option` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
 `value` int(1) NOT NULL
);
```

Then an example of some items and criteria:

```
INSERT INTO items (id, name) VALUES
(1,'Name1'),
(2,'Name2'),
(3,'Name3');

INSERT INTO criteria VALUES
(1,'option1',1) ,(1,'option2',1) ,(1,'option3',0),
(2,'option1',0) ,(2,'option2',1) ,(2,'option3',1),
(3,'option1',1) ,(3,'option2',0) ,(3,'option3',1);
```

This would create 3 items and 3 options and assign options to them.

Now there are multiple way you can order by a certain "strength". The simplest of which would be:

```
SELECT i . * , c1.value + c3.value AS strength
FROM items i
JOIN criteria c1 ON c1.cid = i.id AND c1.option = 'option1'
JOIN criteria c3 ON c3.cid = i.id AND c3.option = 'option3'
ORDER BY strength DESC
```

This would show you all the items that have option 1 or option 3 but those with both options would appear to be ranked "higher.

This works well if you're doing a search on 2 options. But let's assume you make a search on all 3 options. All the items now share the same strength, this is why it's important to assign "weights" to options.

You could make the value your strength, but that might not help you if your queries don't always assign the same weights to the same options everywhere. This can be easily achieved on a per-query basis with the following query:

```
SELECT i.* , IF(c1.value, 2, 0) + IF(c3.value, 1, 0) AS strength
FROM items i
JOIN criteria c1 ON c1.cid = i.id AND c1.option = 'option1'
JOIN criteria c3 ON c3.cid = i.id AND c3.option = 'option3'
ORDER BY strength DESC
```

Try the queries out and see if it's what you need.

I would also like to note that this is not the best solution in terms of processing power. I'd recommend you add indexes, make the option field an integer, cache results wherever possible.

Leave a comment if you have any questions or anything to add.